# Store data for a loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm doing a numerical integration using the Monte Carlo Method. I've managed to make the function work, but now I'm trying to store the results in a matrix, so I can plot everything together.

Here's my error:
    ``Traceback(most recent call last):
      File "mcmc.py", line 41, in 
        result_array = list(fnArea)
    TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable

And here's my code:

```
from math import *
from random import *
import numpy as np

def f(a):
    return sin(a)

amin = 0.0
amax = 2.0*pi

numRep = 100  #quanto maior, mais preciso porem mais devagar
bmin = f(amin)
bmax = bmin
for i in range(numRep):
    a = amin + (amax - amin) * float(i)/numRep
    b = f(a)
    if b < bmin: bmin = b
    if b > bmax: bmax = b

retArea = (amax - amin)*(bmax - bmin) #definicao da integral
numPontos = 100
soma = 0
for j in range(numPontos):
   a = amin + (amax - amin) * random()
   b = bmin + (bmax - bmin) * random()
   if fabs(b) <= fabs(f(a)):
        if f(a) > 0 and b > 0 and b <= f(a):
            soma += 1
        if f(a) < 0 and b < 0 and b >= f(a):
            soma -= 1

fnArea = retArea * float(soma)/numPontos 
print (str(fnArea))

result_array = np.empty((0,100))
count = 100
for i in range(count):
    fnArea = retArea * (soma)/numPontos
    result_array = list(fnArea)


print (result_array)
```

Comment: are you trying to create a list of list and store in `result_array` ? Refer answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error because

```
result_array = list(fnArea)
```

Here you are trying to turn a float into a list which is not valid.

Here is a working code, however I m not really sure about the correctness of the results that you are getting.

Here we are making result_array a 1 D array of zeros and then replacing each column based on i.

```
from math import *
from random import *
import numpy as np

def f(a):
    return sin(a)

amin = 0.0
amax = 2.0*pi

numRep = 100  #quanto maior, mais preciso porem mais devagar
bmin = f(amin)
bmax = bmin
for i in range(numRep):
    a = amin + (amax - amin) * float(i)/numRep
    b = f(a)
    if b < bmin: bmin = b
    if b > bmax: bmax = b

retArea = (amax - amin)*(bmax - bmin) #definicao da integral
numPontos = 100
soma = 0
for j in range(numPontos):
   a = amin + (amax - amin) * random()
   b = bmin + (bmax - bmin) * random()
   if fabs(b) <= fabs(f(a)):
        if f(a) > 0 and b > 0 and b <= f(a):
            soma += 1
        if f(a) < 0 and b < 0 and b >= f(a):
            soma -= 1

fnArea = retArea * float(soma)/numPontos 
print (str(fnArea))

result_array = np.zeros((1,100))
count = 100
for i in range(count):
    fnArea = retArea * (soma)/numPontos
    result_array[0,i] = fnArea


print (result_array)
```

Answer (score 0):

You got this error because you were trying to convert `float` object [number] to `list` [which is iterable].

If you are trying to create a list of lists having values of `fnArea`. I have modified your `result_array`  declaration to python list instead if numpy array and append the value of `fnArea` in `for` loop. Please see answer below:

```
from math import *
from random import *
import numpy as np

def f(a):
    return sin(a)

amin = 0.0
amax = 2.0*pi

numRep = 100  #quanto maior, mais preciso porem mais devagar
bmin = f(amin)
bmax = bmin
for i in range(numRep):
    a = amin + (amax - amin) * float(i)/numRep
    b = f(a)
    if b < bmin: bmin = b
    if b > bmax: bmax = b

retArea = (amax - amin)*(bmax - bmin) #definicao da integral
numPontos = 100
soma = 0
for j in range(numPontos):
   a = amin + (amax - amin) * random()
   b = bmin + (bmax - bmin) * random()
   if fabs(b) <= fabs(f(a)):
        if f(a) > 0 and b > 0 and b <= f(a):
            soma += 1
        if f(a) < 0 and b < 0 and b >= f(a):
            soma -= 1

fnArea = retArea * float(soma)/numPontos 
print (str(fnArea))

result_array = []
count = 100
for i in range(count):
    fnArea = retArea * (soma)/numPontos
    print fnArea
    result_array.append([fnArea])



print (result_array)
```